# Compiling Jython for web apps in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jython

I have PyDev set up in Eclipse to do Jython web development. Instead of using the Jython interpreter to handle my servlets I prefer to use the Jython compiler instead for a particular project I'm working on.

Within Eclipse I use Tomcat to test my web apps. The sort of process that I'm looking for is would be very similar to standard Java web development. I'd like to do something like;

- Put my Jython scripts in the source folder.
- Have the Jython compiler compile the scripts into Java classes when I republish to the Tomcat server.

Pretty much the same as if I would use Java but with Jython scripts instead. I'm having trouble setting this process up in Eclipse. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a look at [snakefight](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/snakefight)

Comment: Nice. But's that more of a deployment thing rather than for development.